# Using IMAPClient in Python to fetch email - need data to be stored in a list

Tags: php, python, email, dictionary, imapclient

Happy New Year to all of you :)

I built a web form where new employees enter their data and have it send to an email address where I receive about 20 "sets" of data coming from PHP.

```
Vorname: $firstname  
Nachname: $lastname
```

and so on.

Now, when I fetch the email with python using IMAPClient I remove the MIME characters before and after the main message and am left with the following set of strings:

```
"\r\nNachname: Doe\r\nVorname: John\r\nStraße: Bahnhofstraße 3a\r\nPLZ: 67346\r\nOrt: Speyer\r\nGeschlecht: maennlich\r\nGeburtsdatum: 10.07.1983\r\nGeburtsname: \r\nGeburtsort: Speyer\r\nFamilienstand: ledig\r\nNationalität: deutsch\r\nKonfession: katholisch\r\nTelefon_1: 017666666666\r\nTelefon_2: \r\nHandy: \r\nE-Mail: mail@mail.com\r\nFax: \r\nQualifikation: hwfach\r\nAbschluss: fachhauswirtsch\r\nAufmerksam_durch: pdienstleist, zeitung\r\n"
```

I tried to `.replace("\r","")` and `\n` but key and value seem to be off.

Wondering how you guys would solve this problem?

I have a working script with a in-code dictionary - so the only thing missing now is a way to excerpt a dictionary from the email.

Hopefully someone can help me.

Cheers

Comment: Can you translate it to english? Which are the keys and which are the values?

Comment: Sorry - It would look like this:

"\r\nLastName: Doe\r\nFirstName: John\r\nAddress: Bahnhofstraße 3a\r\nZIP: 67346\r\nCity: Speyer\r\nSex: maennlich\r\nDOB: 10.07.1983\r\nBirthname: \r\nBirthplace: Speyer\r\nMaritalStatus: ledig\r\nNationality: deutsch\r\nReligion: katholisch\r\nPhone_1: 017666666666\r\nPhone_2: \r\nMobile: \r\nEMail: mail@mail.com\r\nFax: \r\nQualification: hwfach\r\nGraduation: fachhauswirtsch\r\nFoundWhere: pdienstleist, zeitung\r\n"

so the Key would be LastName, FirstName, Address, ZIP, City, DOB etc. 
The values are the user input-data like Doe, John, Bahnhofstraße

Comment: I think @karthikr gave the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your goal is to convert this string to a dictionary, you can do something like this:

First split it by `\r\n` (where `x` is the string)

```
k_vs = x.split("\r\n")
```

Now, you can use a dict comprehension to create the dictionary

```
_dct = {i.split(":")[0].strip():i.split(":")[1].strip() for i in k_vs if i}
```

If you would prefer more verbose, a for loop would do the same thing:

```
_dct = {}
for i in k_vs:
    if i:
        key, value = i.split(":")
        _dct.update({key: value})
```

DEMO:

```
>>> x = "\r\nNachname: Doe\r\nVorname: John\r\nStraße: Bahnhofstraße 3a\r\nPLZ: 67346\r\nOrt: Speyer\r\nGeschlecht: maennlich\r\nGeburtsdatum: 10.07.1983\r\nGeburtsname: \r\nGeburtsort: Speyer\r\nFamilienstand: ledig\r\nNationalität: deutsch\r\nKonfession: katholisch\r\nTelefon_1: 017666666666\r\nTelefon_2: \r\nHandy: \r\nE-Mail: mail@mail.com\r\nFax: \r\nQualifikation: hwfach\r\nAbschluss: fachhauswirtsch\r\nAufmerksam_durch: pdienstleist, zeitung\r\n"
>>> 
>>> y = x.split("\r\n")
>>> z = {i.split(":")[0].strip():i.split(":")[1].strip() for i in y if i}
>>> z
{'Geburtsdatum': '10.07.1983', 'Familienstand': 'ledig', 'Konfession': 'katholisch', 'Aufmerksam_durch': 'pdienstleist, zeitung', 'Ort': 'Speyer', 'Telefon_2': '', 'Vorname': 'John', 'PLZ': '67346', 'Geburtsname': '', 'Nationalit\xc3\xa4t': 'deutsch', 'E-Mail': 'mail@mail.com', 'Nachname': 'Doe', 'Telefon_1': '017666666666', 'Qualifikation': 'hwfach', 'Geburtsort': 'Speyer', 'Geschlecht': 'maennlich', 'Abschluss': 'fachhauswirtsch', 'Handy': '', 'Stra\xc3\x9fe': 'Bahnhofstra\xc3\x9fe 3a', 'Fax': ''}
>>>
```

Comment: why underscore in _dct?

Comment: Its a local variable name. use whatever you like.. I like `_dct`

Comment: :D I know. Was just curious if you have some special reasoning :)

Comment: You need to cover first and the last elements I guess. The first and last elements will be empty strings?

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks a lot karthikr!! That did it.
The empty strings as MYGz stated are possible since some of the fields (like Fax, Birthname) are optional :)

Awesome <3

Comment: @rawk Nah. he has it covered with an if condition. I din't see it.